# jq: Convert json to text

Tags: json, bash, shell, sh, jq

Below is the json content, need to create new key using `jq` via merging outer key with inner key and setting their value same as inner key value.

```
{
  "es": {
    "host": "https://es-host.ap-south-1.es.amazonaws.com",
    "user": "es_admin",
    "pass": "pa$$w0rd"
  },
  "db": {
    "host": "https://db-host.ap-south-1.es.amazonaws.com",
    "user": "db_admin",
    "pass": "pa$$w0rd"
  }   
}
```

Expected output:

```
ES_HOST="https://es-host.ap-south-1.es.amazonaws.com"
ES_USER="es_admin"
ES_PASS="pa$$w0rd"

DB_HOST="https://db-host.ap-south-1.es.amazonaws.com"
DB_USER="db_admin"
DB_PASS="pa$$w0rd"
```

Tried couple of combination with jq but unable to do needful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: please update the question your `jq` attempts and the (wrong) output generated by said attempts

Comment: my bad, I was masking real data, mistakenly skipped. Updated now.

Comment: See: [unix command formatting flattening nested json objects data](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/441746/74329)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way would be to use `paths` to traverse the document, and `getpath` to retrieve the value at that path:

```bash
jq -r '
  paths(strings) as $path
  | "\($path | map(ascii_upcase) | join("_"))=\(getpath($path) | @json)"
'
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/xaHwNrW5wg8)

Another way would be using `.key` and `.value` from the items provided by `to_entries`, employed twice thus going down exactly two levels:

```bash
jq -r '
  to_entries[] | "\(.key | ascii_upcase)_\(.value
    | to_entries[] | "\(.key | ascii_upcase)=\(.value | @json)"
  )"
'
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/MeR51zlq7sn)

Output (depending on its purpose, you might want to change `@json` to `@sh`):

```
ES_HOST="https://es-host.ap-south-1.es.amazonaws.com"
ES_USER="es_admin"
ES_PASS="pa$$w0rd"
DB_HOST="https://db-host.ap-south-1.es.amazonaws.com"
DB_USER="db_admin"
DB_PASS="pa$$w0rd"
```